# backbone-aura event emmission

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, aura.js

I have recently started learning [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and [aura](https://github.com/aurajs/aura) and tried out a simple app using both. I have three widgets, say A, B and C. Now A and B publish events (using sandbox.emit) and C subscribes to them (using sandbox.on). 'A' publishes "A.eventA" and 'B' publishes "B.eventB" say. I tried publishing "B.eventB" from widget A and it still works.
So, is there a way using which widgets cannot publish any events except there own events ? (Or is this allowed/expected behaviour ?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking about is security.  Aura's design is to have a facade that handles security.  Instead of hitting the mediator's `publish` directly, you call it through the facade.  The facade first checks that you have permission to publish.

Here's an example from https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1518268 which shows security for `subscribe`.  You could use something similar for `publish`.

```js
define([ "../aura/mediator" , "../aura/permissions" ], 
       function (mediator, permissions){

    var facade = facade || {};

    facade.subscribe = function(subscriber, channel, callback){

        // Note: Handling permissions/security is optional here
        // The permissions check can be removed 
        // to just use the mediator directly.

        if(permissions.validate(subscriber, channel)){
            mediator.subscribe( channel, callback );
        }
    }

    facade.publish = function(channel){
        mediator.publish( channel );
    }
    return facade;

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I also came across the same approach.